# ¿Cómo crear una tabla dinámica de Excel con Python?

Tags: python, excel, pivot, tabla-dinámica

Estuve investigando maneras de crear tablas dinámicas de excel con python y llegué a este código:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Producto': ['Producto A', 'Producto B', 'Producto C'],
    'Cantidad': [10, 15, 20],
    'Precio unitario': [5, 7, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with pd.ExcelWriter('tabla_dinamica.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)
    pivot_sheet = writer.book.add_worksheet('Pivot')
    pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Producto', values=['Precio unitario'], aggfunc='sum')
    pivot_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot')

print("-----FIN-----")
```

Creo muy bien la tabla pero no es una tabla dinámica, es decir, es la tabla dinámica pegada como valores, yo quiero poder editarla, que aparezcan las opciones de Analizar tabla dinámica y Diseño. Intente con Aspose pero mi organización no permite instalar java.

---

Por supuesto, el código que me brindas me da una tabla:

[image: Tabla]

Y lo que yo requiero es una tabla dinámica:

[image: Tabla Dinámica]

Al dar clic a la tabla dinámica se debe mostrar la lista de campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Aunque supongo que habrá alguna manera de hacer lo que pides con pandas, te recomiendo utilizar `openpyxl`, librería especializada en excel que contiene muchísimas más funciones.

Aplicando este método a tu código quedaría así:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# Crear un DataFrame con los datos
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Producto": ["Producto 1", "Producto 2", "Producto 3"],
    "Región": ["Región 1", "Región 2", "Región 3"],
    "Ventas": [100, 200, 300]
})

workbook = Workbook() # Utilizar load_workbook(file_name) para abrir un archivo existente
sheet = workbook.active # Devuelve la página actual

# Iteramos sobre las keys del dataframe y los añadimos en la fila 1 y su respectiva columna
for key in range(len(df.keys())):
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=key+1).value = df.keys()[key]
    # Lo mismo pero con las values
    for value in range(len(df.values[key])):
        sheet.cell(row=value+2, column=key+1).value = df.values[value][key]

# Creamos una tabla con su nombre y sus dimensiones = "esquina_superior_izquierda:esquina_inferior_derecha"
tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref=sheet.dimensions)

# Aplicamos un estilo a la tabla
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                   showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style

# Añadimos la tabla a la hoja
sheet.add_table(tab)

# Finalmente, guardamos en el mismo archivo
workbook.save("tabla_dinamica.xlsx")
```

Te dejo [aquí un tutorial](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/) muy bueno con el que acabo de aprender a utilizar la librería.

En [este otro link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) tienes muchos ejemplos haciendo uso de todas las funciones de la librería.

Como nota personal te recomiendo crear funciones para mejorar tu código y poder reutilizarlas en este tipo de trabajos, en los cuales suele repetirse mucho código.

Como próximos pasos para mejorar estarían la implementación de formulas en una tabla o un condicional para el color de los valores de las ventas

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pero el código que me brindas crea una tabla, no una tabla dinámica.

Comment: Podrías añadir una imagen con el resultado obtenido y otro con el resultado objetivo para hacerme una idea de lo que pides, por favor? Si me proporcionas eso puedo modificar la respuesta acorde con tus necesidades